# How to insert <br> in markaby (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, markaby

I have to do something like this

Freeze
 2010-6-1

How can i write it in markaby?
Now I have:
td "#{user.username} #{user.created_at}"

Comment: use td "#{user.username} <br /> #{user.created_at}"

Comment: and this will generate the string "Freeze &lt; br/&gt; 2010-6-1"

Comment: try:"#{user.username} <br /> #{user.created_at}".html_safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the correct answer is:

```
td do
  text "#{user.username}"
  br
  text "#{user.created_at}"
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Im not sure, but try this:

```
td do
    user.username user.created_at :br
end
```

Answer (score -1):

try this it may work for you

```
td do
    user.username {br} user.created_at 
end
```

Comment: and it's display only a user.username

Comment: td do
    user.username + " <br/> "+ user.created_at 
end

Comment: Are you try to compile it for yourself, before comment my question?